# How create Category From Frontend in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to create a category from front end , i have a code

```
 <?php
     $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
     $category->setName('mobiles')
     setIsActive(1)                       //activate your category
     setIsAnchor(0)
     setCustomDesignApply(1)
     setDisplayMode( 'PRODUCTS' )
     setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId());
     $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load("2");
     $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
     $category->save();
     unset($category);
  ?>
```

this code is working fine in single store, but in multi-store the category is not in active mode.
please guys help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-store, you have to set the `store_id`

`$category->setStoreId(0);` **// 0 = default/all store view.**

If you want to save data for a specific store view, replace 0 by your `store_id`

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
```